# IBM AIX find src_dir -type d -exec mkdir -p "dst_dir/{}" \; doesn't work

Tags: find, aix, mkdir

I'm trying to copy directory structure from src_dir to dst_dir.

On my CentOS 6.4 Linux Bash this command works fine.

```
[localhost]$ find src_dir   
src_dir     
src_dir/dir2    
src_dir/dir2/dir4   
src_dir/dir1   
src_dir/dir1/test.txt   
src_dir/dir1/dir3

[localhost]$ find src_dir -type d -exec mkdir -p "dst_dir/{}" \;   

[localhost]$ find dst_dir    
dst_dir/src_dir    
dst_dir/src_dir/dir2    
dst_dir/src_dir/dir1    
dst_dir/src_dir/dir1/dir3
```

But, when I'm doing the same command in IBM AIX 6.1, I got this output

```
[aix61:/data]find dst_dir    
dst_dir    
dst_dir/{}
```

Maybe the 'find' command parameter {} replacement is somewhat different in AIX.
But I don't know how to solve it.
Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is not POSIX. Only a standalone `{}` (on its own argument) is guaranteed to be expanded.

Use:

```
find src_dir -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir do
  mkdir -p "dst_dir/$dir"; done' sh {} +
```

Or to avoid running one `mkdir` per directory:

```
find src_dir -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir do
  set -- "$@" "dst_dir/$dir"; shift; done
  mkdir -p "$@"' sh {} +
```

(though there's a risk of reaching the "arg list too large" condition).

Note that it would create `dst_dir/src_dir/x/y...`. If you wanted `dst_dir/x/y...`, you'd do:

```
find src_dir -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir do
  set -- "$@" "dst_dir${dir#src_dir}"; shift; done
  mkdir -p "$@"' sh {} +
```

---

Another option, if you can guarantee that directory paths don't contain newline characters would be to use `pax`:

```
find src_dir -type d | pax -rw dst_dir
```

That would allow you do also copy the directories metadata like ownership and permissions (with `-pe`)

To remove the leading `src_dir` component in the destination:

```
find src_dir -path '*/*' -type d | pax -'s@^src_dir/@@' -rw dst_dir
```

Or:

```
(cd src_dir && find . -type d | pax -rw ../dst_dir)
```